# Using LDAP in WPF to find specific user in an Active Directory

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory, ldap

In WPF and therefore in the C# programming language, I am trying to use LDAP to find a specific user within an Active Directory. I was able to check if a specific user exists in an Active Directory but I was not able to retrieve that user from the directory in order to gain access to their properties.

I am using the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Is there a way to do what I seek to achieve, is there a way to retrieve a specific user from the AD using LDAP in order to check their properties?

EDIT: code I used to check if user is in AD. Returns true if user is in AD, false if user is not found. I wonder thought if there is a limit to the number of users it will search.

```
bool ContainsUser(string domain, string userName)
        {
            string ldapBase = string.Format("LDAP://{0}", domain);

            using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapBase))
            {
                using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
                {
                    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", userName);
                    return searcher.FindOne() != null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you check if the user exists? You probably just need a small change to get the attributes you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate using `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`

for example:

```
    public static string GetEmailAddressFromActiveDirectoryUserName(string adUserName)
    {
        string email = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(adUserName))
        {
            using (var pctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                using (UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pctx, adUserName))
                {
                    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(up?.EmailAddress) ? up.EmailAddress : string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
        return email;
    }
```

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.findbyidentity?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: A couple of questions. This uses the namespace "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement". Does that still fall under LDAP?
Also I'm not familiar with some of the syntax. What does the "?" in "up?.EmailAddress" do?
And, is there a limit to how many entries in the AD that it can search?

Comment: "?." is a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Answer (score 0):

The code you use to check that the user exists in AD or not already loads user properties: `searcher.FindOne()?.Properties`.

```
public class User
{
    public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

User GetAdUser(string domain, string userName)
{
    string ldapBase = string.Format("LDAP://{0}", domain);

    using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapBase))
    {
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
        {
            searcher.Filter = string.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", userName);
            var result = searcher.FindOne();
            User user = null;
            if (result != null)
            {
                // result.Properties - list of loaded user properties
                // result.Properties.PropertyNames - list of user property names                
                user = new User
                {
                    UserPrincipalName = result.Properties["userprincipalname"].Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault();
                    Name = result.Properties["name"].Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```